# Сохранение вложений писем

Tags: indy, delphi, delphi-7, email

Добрый час, уважаемые программисты!
Сохраняю письма вложений следующим образом:

```
TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[intIndex]).SaveToFile(file);
```

Сохраняется всё замечательно, однако заметил, что если сохраняемые файлы имеют одинаковые названия, то возникает ошибка сохранения. Мне необходимо заменить существующий файл на последний. Существует ли какой-нибудь встроенный метод либо какая-либо альтернатива?

Comment: [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Спасибо, а есть пример?

Comment: [Полно](http://f1-delphi.ru/books/delphi_tryuki_i_effekty/imena_dlya_vremennyx_faylov/). указываете префикс в виде вашего имени файла, получаете имя, которое сто процентов будет не занято.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а возможно чтобы он генерировал не случайные имена, а конкретные?

Comment: @АлександрЪ, смысл этой функции как раз в том, чтоб не проверять существует ли файл. если вам надо генерить ваши имена, тогда вручную придется проверять существует файл или нет. вам решать что нужнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uses SysUtils;
...
if FileExists(file) then
  DeleteFile(file);
TIdAttachment(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[intIndex]).SaveToFile(file);
```

`file` - плохое имя для переменной, пересекается с ключевыми словами языка. Лучше `FileName`.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Благодарю!
Да, Вы правы на счет переменной, я ее только здесь так обозвал))
За способ - благодарю, однако, решил заменять имена файлов с целью сохранения всех версий (т. е. qwe.jpg, qwe(1).jpg, qwe(2).jpg ...).

Comment: @АлександрЪ
Тоже вариант